# Seperate html pages for each screen in Jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am newbie to Jquery Mobile, so far what ever examples i searched contains only one html page for whole application, with multipe div tags where each page/screen is defined as div tag with data-role as page with some header and footers optionally. Based on user actions, we are hiding some div's(pages) and showing only expected page. Also, this multi-page template seems to be standard design, as written by some blogs. Are there any other designing ways? what I would like to have is multipe html pages, for ex one for login, one for home, one for contact etc. Other wise it is difficult to understand/code/debug issues, especially people from Java background like me.So, what I want is some kind of MVC design with JQueryMobile, like each view/screen as sepearate html associated with one js (Controller). Can we have multiple html pages in JqueryMobile app? If possible how to pass data/ maintain session between them? Any samples are most welcome. Thanks In Advance.

Note: Also I don't want server side includes, may app contains 10 to 15 screens, each page will make a webservice call and fetch some data and map it to UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple html files if you want. jQuery Mobile will automatic include these with AJAX: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Anyways, jQuery Mobile recommends one big html file with multiple pages.

From http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-template.html

> This template is standard HTML document with a single "page" container inside, unlike a multi-page template that has multiple pages within it. **We strongly recommend building your site or app as a series of separate pages** like this because it's cleaner, more lightweight and works better without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As jerone mentioned above, the jQuery Mobile documentation clearly says

> We strongly recommend building your site or app as a series of separate pages like this because it's cleaner, more lightweight and works better without JavaScript.

See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-template.html

Each page (which can be a static HTML file or anything produced by a script (e.g PHP, Python or whatever)) is thus standalone and transitions from one page to another are done using AJAX calls.

There is no such thing as a controller except if you assume that your browser is one!